# Flutter: How can i put the text widget center in screen

Tags: flutter, dart, text, widget, flutter-layout

I need to put the title' in the center even to fit any screen, I know can I sized box to move the title in the center, but when using the different device the dimensions surely will change and become the title the different places.
this is code :

```
class NotificationDoctor extends StatelessWidget {
  TextStyles textStyles = TextStyles.HEADING;
  Texts texts;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15.0))),
        height: 130.h,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.h),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: 15.w,
                  top: 15.h,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    FlatButton(
                      child: ArrowIcon(
                        arrowColor: Color(0xFFEEF4F9),
                        backgroundColor:
                            Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(.9),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    // SizedBox(
                    //   width: 55,
                    // ),
                    Center(
                      child: Texts(
                        'Notifications',
                        style: TextStyles.HEADING,
                        color: Color(0xFFEEF4F9),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the padding like this

```
Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.h, horizontal: 3.h),
      child: Container(),
    );
```

read more at https://pub.dev/packages/sizer